# Knockout js unable to bind data using observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display all the employees in the database and I am unable to achieve it.

My JS,

```
var EmployeeKoViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.EmpId = ko.observable("");
    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.City = ko.observable("");
    self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);
    GetEmployees();
    function GetEmployees() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Employee/About",
        }).done(function (data) {

            self.Employees.push(data);


        }).error(function (ex) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }


}
$(document).ready(function myfunction() {
    ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeKoViewModel());
})
```

And my View,

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td>
                <div class="FixedContainer">
                    <table data-bind="visible:  Employees().length>0" style="border: double">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EmpId</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>City</td>

                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach:  Employees">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: EmpId"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: City"></td>

                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

There is no data showing up in UI .I have checked console in browser but no errors.

Can you guide Where I am doing wrong please.

```
data
[
ObjectCity: "Hyderabad"
EmpId: 1Name: "Vivek"
__proto__: Object
]
```

Comment: `self.Employees.push(data);` should be `self.Employees(data);`, try that way. And you dont need - `self.EmpId = ko.observable("");
    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.City = ko.observable("");`

Comment: What is the data that is returned from a call to `"/Employee/About"`? Can you add a sample?

Comment: @ramiramilu That worked. Previuosly i have taken the same Observable array but i have pushed and it worked

Comment: Glad I am helpful. I posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.Employees.push(data);` should be `self.Employees(data);`